# Embedding fonts flattening a document with XFAFlattener

Tags: itext

I'm flattening an existing document with XFA_Worker. Is there a way to force fonts to be embedded in the flattened document?

```
using iText = iTextSharp.text;
using iTextPDF = iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextImage = iTextSharp.text.Image;
using iTextReader = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader;
using iTextWriter = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

reader = new iTextReader(tempFileDirectory + "\\" + "orig_" + tmpFileName);

iTextPDF.AcroFields form = reader.AcroFields;
iTextPDF.XfaForm xfa = form.Xfa; 

if (xfa.XfaPresent)
{
    iText.Document document = new iText.Document();
    iTextWriter writer = iTextWriter.GetInstance(document,
        new FileStream(tempFileDirectory + "\\" + tmpFileName, FileMode.Create));

    XFAFlattener xfaf = new XFAFlattener(document, writer);
    xfaf.Flatten(reader);
    document.Close();
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `iTextReader` or `iTextWriter` in the official version of iText. Please explain where you got those classes.

Comment: There are a couple of using statement

Comment: using iText = iTextSharp.text;
using iTextPDF = iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextImage = iTextSharp.text.Image;
using iTextReader = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader;
using iTextWriter = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

Comment: Are you saying that you introduced aliases for classes such as `PdfReader` and `PdfWriter`? Please understand that this is very confusing when you ask people for advice. Especially since it shields the fact that you are using `PdfWriter` while you may want to use `PdfAWriter` instead: `PdfAWriter` will tell you whenever you're *accidentally* using a font that isn't embedded (take a look at a PDF/A example first).

Comment: Sorry about the aliasing - I inherited the code base from someone else. (Thanks for the editing, Chris)
I also tried using the PdfAWriter, and it throws an exception, when the original document has fonts that are not embedded. So my question is - can I force the flattener to embed fonts that are not embedded in the original document?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just provide a `FontProvider` that forces the fonts to be embedded.

Answer (score 2):

For a specific project, I have HTML that requires a regular font and a bold font that are embedded. The requirements for the PDF are also very strict: I am not allowed to use any font other than OpenSans and OpenSans bold, and the text has to be stored as UNICODE (no simple fonts allowed).

To meet these requirements, I wrote the following implementation of the `FontProvider` interface:

```
class MyFontProvider implements FontProvider {

    protected BaseFont regular;
    protected BaseFont bold;

    public MyFontProvider() throws DocumentException, IOException {
        regular = BaseFont.createFont("resources/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
        bold = BaseFont.createFont("resources/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
    }

    public boolean isRegistered(String fontname) {
        return true;
    }

    public Font getFont(String fontname, String encoding, boolean embedded, float size, int style, BaseColor color) {
        Font font;
        switch (style) {
            case Font.BOLD:
                font = new Font(bold, size);
                break;
            default:
                font = new Font(regular, size);
        }
        font.setColor(color);
        return font;
    }
}
```

I create two `BaseFont` instances in the constructor. In the `getFont()` method, I ignore the `fontname`, `encoding` and `embedded` parameters. I will always return embedded OpenSans using Identity-H as "encoding". I do apply the font size, font color, and the style (but only in case the style is set to bold; in all other cases, I use the regular font). You can adapt this `FontProvider` any way you like, but in my case, these were strict requirements for the project.

Obviously, I need the "long" version of the XML Worker code because I now need to declare `MyFontProvider` to the HTML pipeline:

```
// CSS
CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(new FileInputStream(CSS));
cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

// HTML
CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(new MyFontProvider());
HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

// Pipelines
PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

// XML Worker
XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(invoice));
```

Every time XML Worker needs a font, it will call `MyFontProvider` and the `getFont()` method will return no other font than embedded OpenSans or OpenSans-Bold.

The same principle exists for XFA Flattener where you can also work with `CssAppliers` and `FontProvider` implementations. As XFA Worker is a closed source product, which means that you are either using the trial version or that you are a customer of iText Group. In both cases, you should contact iText Group directly if this answer doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, we are currently evaluating the product, so I'll talk to iText Group.

I'll take a look at IFontProvider and see, if I can get XFAFlattener to talk to it when flattening a LiveCycle Document